# How to demonize one image of a docker-compose composition?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose consisting of three images, `project_a`, `project_b`, `project_c`.

I can run:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

which will start all the images in the background not printing their output to the current shell.

I can also just start a specific image by:

```
docker-compose up project_b
```

Yet this will print the log of project_b to the shell.

Hence, I thought I can just run:

```
docker-compose up project_b -d
```

Yet this will throw:

```
ERROR: No such service -d
```

How to just start one container in a docker-compose stack in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order does matter, as:

```
 docker-compose -d project_b
```

will run fine. If the option flag is at the end, it will be read as an image name.

Comment: FYI: I created an [issue for docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2457) about this weird behavior.